# Reading XML data in Java JSP - Premature end of file error

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to get my JSP to parse an XML file so that I can output certain information in a table. Unfortunately, it keeps giving me a premature end of file error, and I'm not entirely sure how I would fix this.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>cust_xml</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Customer Information</h1>
    <c:import var="xmlFile" url="CUST.xml" />
    <x:parse var="myDoc" xml="${xmlFile}" />

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Customer Number</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      <x:forEach select="$myDoc/CUSTOMERS/Customer" var="cust">
        <tr>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustNo" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustFirstName" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustLastName" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustStreet" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustCity" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustState" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustZip" /></td>
          <td><x:out select="$cust/CustBal" /></td>
        </tr>
      </x:forEach>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <CUSTOMERS>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C0954327</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Sheri</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Gordon</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>336 Hill St.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Littleton</CustCity>
            <CustState>CO</CustState>
            <CustZip>80129-5543</CustZip>
            <CustBal>230</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C1010398</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Jim</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Glussman</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>1432 E. Ravenna</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Denver</CustCity>
            <CustState>CO</CustState>
            <CustZip>80111-0033</CustZip>
            <CustBal>200</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C2388597</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Beth</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Taylor</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>2396 Rafter Rd</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Seattle</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98103-1121</CustZip>
            <CustBal>500</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C3340959</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Betty</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Wise</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>4334 153rd NW</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Seattle</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98178-3311</CustZip>
            <CustBal>200</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C3499503</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Bob</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Mann</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>1190 Lorraine Cir.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Monroe</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98013-1095</CustZip>
            <CustBal>0</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C8543321</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Ron</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Thompson</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>789 122nd St.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Renton</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98666-1289</CustZip>
            <CustBal>85</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C8574932</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Wally</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Jones</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>411 Webber Ave.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Seattle</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98105-1093</CustZip>
            <CustBal>1500</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C8654390</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Candy</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Kendall</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>456 Pine St.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Seattle</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98105-3345</CustZip>
            <CustBal>50</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9128574</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Jerry</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Wyatt</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>16212 123rd Ct.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Denver</CustCity>
            <CustState>CO</CustState>
            <CustZip>80222-0022</CustZip>
            <CustBal>100</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9403348</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Mike</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Boren</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>642 Crest Ave.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Englewood</CustCity>
            <CustState>CO</CustState>
            <CustZip>80113-5431</CustZip>
            <CustBal>0</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9432910</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Larry</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Styles</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>9825 S. Crest Lane</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Bellevue</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98104-2211</CustZip>
            <CustBal>250</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9543029</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Sharon</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Johnson</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>1223 Meyer Way</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Fife</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98222-1123</CustZip>
            <CustBal>856</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9549302</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Todd</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Hayes</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>1400 NW 88th</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Lynnwood</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98036-2244</CustZip>
            <CustBal>0</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9857432</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Homer</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Wells</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>123 Main St.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Seattle</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98105-4322</CustZip>
            <CustBal>500</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9865874</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Mary</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Hill</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>206 McCaffrey</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Littleton</CustCity>
            <CustState>CO</CustState>
            <CustZip>80129-5543</CustZip>
            <CustBal>150</CustBal>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustNo>C9943201</CustNo>
            <CustFirstName>Harry</CustFirstName>
            <CustLastName>Sanders</CustLastName>
            <CustStreet>1280 S. Hill Rd.</CustStreet>
            <CustCity>Fife</CustCity>
            <CustState>WA</CustState>
            <CustZip>98222-2258</CustZip>
            <CustBal>1000</CustBal>
        </Customer>
    </CUSTOMERS>
    <PRODUCTS>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P0036566</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>17 inch Color Monitor</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>ColorMeg, Inc.</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>12</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>169</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P0036577</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>19 inch Color Monitor</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>ColorMeg, Inc.</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>10</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>319</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P1114590</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>R3000 Color Laser Printer</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Connex</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>5</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>699</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>10 Foot Printer Cable</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Ethlite</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>100</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>12</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>8-Outlet Surge Protector</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Intersafe</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>33</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>14.99</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>CVP Ink Jet Color Printer</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Connex</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>8</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>99</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P3455443</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>Color Ink Jet Cartridge</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Connex</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>24</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>38</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P4200344</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>36-Bit Color Scanner</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>UV Components</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>16</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>199.99</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P6677900</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>Black Ink Jet Cartridge</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Connex</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>44</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>25.69</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProdNo>P9995676</ProdNo>
            <ProdName>Battery Back-up System</ProdName>
            <ProdMfg>Cybercx</ProdMfg>
            <ProdQOH>12</ProdQOH>
            <ProdPrice>89</ProdPrice>
        </Product>
    </PRODUCTS>
    <EMPLOYEES>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E1329594</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Landi</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>Santos</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(303) 789-1234</EmpPhone>
            <SupEmpNo>E8843211</SupEmpNo>
            <EmpCommRate>0.02</EmpCommRate>
            <EmpEmail>LSantos@bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E8544399</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Joe</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>Jenkins</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(303) 221-9875</EmpPhone>
            <SupEmpNo>E8843211</SupEmpNo>
            <EmpCommRate>0.02</EmpCommRate>
            <EmpEmail>JJenkins@ bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E8843211</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Amy</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>Tang</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(303) 556-4321</EmpPhone>
            <SupEmpNo>E9884325</SupEmpNo>
            <EmpCommRate>0.04</EmpCommRate>
            <EmpEmail>ATang@ bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E9345771</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Colin</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>White</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(303) 221-4453</EmpPhone>
            <SupEmpNo>E9884325</SupEmpNo>
            <EmpCommRate>0.04</EmpCommRate>
            <EmpEmail>CWhite@ bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E9884325</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Thomas</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>Johnson</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(303) 556-9987</EmpPhone>
            <EmpCommRate>0.05</EmpCommRate>
            <EmpEmail>TJohnson@ bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E9954302</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Mary</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>Hill</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(303) 556-9871</EmpPhone>
            <SupEmpNo>E8843211</SupEmpNo>
            <EmpCommRate>0.02</EmpCommRate>
            <EmpEmail>MHill@ bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmpNo>E9973110</EmpNo>
            <EmpFirstName>Theresa</EmpFirstName>
            <EmpLastName>Beck</EmpLastName>
            <EmpPhone>(720) 320-2234</EmpPhone>
            <SupEmpNo>E9884325</SupEmpNo>
            <EmpEmail>TBeck@bigco.com</EmpEmail>
        </Employee>
    </EMPLOYEES>
    <ORDERS>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1116324</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-23T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C0954327</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E8544399</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Sheri Gordon</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>336 Hill St.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Littleton</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>CO</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>80129-5543</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1231231</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-23T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9432910</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9954302</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Larry Styles</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>9825 S. Crest Lane</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Bellevue</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98104-2211</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1241518</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-02-10T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9549302</CustNo>
            <OrdName>Todd Hayes</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>1400 NW 88th</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Lynnwood</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98036-2244</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1455122</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-09T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C8574932</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9345771</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Wally Jones</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>411 Webber Ave.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98105-1093</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1579999</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-05T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9543029</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E8544399</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Tom Johnson</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>1632 Ocean Dr.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Des Moines</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98222-1123</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1615141</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-23T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C8654390</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E8544399</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Candy Kendall</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>456 Pine St.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98105-3345</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O1656777</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-02-11T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C8543321</CustNo>
            <OrdName>Ron Thompson</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>789 122nd St.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Renton</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98666-1289</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O2233457</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-12T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C2388597</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9884325</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Beth Taylor</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>2396 Rafter Rd</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98103-1121</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O2334661</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-14T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C0954327</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E1329594</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Mrs. Ruth Gordon</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>233 S. 166th</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98011</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O3252629</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-23T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9403348</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9954302</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Mike Boren</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>642 Crest Ave.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Englewood</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>CO</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>80113-5431</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O3331222</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-13T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C1010398</CustNo>
            <OrdName>Jim Glussman</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>1432 E. Ravenna</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Denver</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>CO</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>80111-0033</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O3377543</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-15T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9128574</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E8843211</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Jerry Wyatt</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>16212 123rd Ct.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Denver</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>CO</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>80222-0022</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O4714645</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-11T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C2388597</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E1329594</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Beth Taylor</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>2396 Rafter Rd</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98103-1121</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O5511365</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-22T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C3340959</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9884325</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Betty White</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>4334 153rd NW</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98178-3311</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O6565656</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-20T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9865874</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E8843211</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Mr. Jack Sibley</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>166 E. 344th</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Renton</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98006-5543</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O7847172</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-23T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9943201</CustNo>
            <OrdName>Harry Sanders</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>1280 S. Hill Rd.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Fife</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98222-2258</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O7959898</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-02-19T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C8543321</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E8544399</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Ron Thompson</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>789 122nd St.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Renton</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98666-1289</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O7989497</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-16T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C3499503</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9345771</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Bob Mann</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>1190 Lorraine Cir.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Monroe</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98013-1095</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O8979495</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-01-23T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9865874</CustNo>
            <OrdName>HelenSibley</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>206 McCaffrey</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Renton</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98006-5543</OrdZip>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrdNo>O9919699</OrdNo>
            <OrdDate>2007-02-11T00:00:00</OrdDate>
            <CustNo>C9857432</CustNo>
            <EmpNo>E9954302</EmpNo>
            <OrdName>Homer Wells</OrdName>
            <OrdStreet>123 Main St.</OrdStreet>
            <OrdCity>Seattle</OrdCity>
            <OrdState>WA</OrdState>
            <OrdZip>98105-4322</OrdZip>
        </Order>
    </ORDERS>
    <ORDERLINES>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1116324</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1231231</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036566</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1231231</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1241518</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036577</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1455122</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P4200344</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1579999</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1579999</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P6677900</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1579999</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P9995676</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1615141</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036566</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1615141</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1615141</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P4200344</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1656777</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O1656777</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O2233457</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036577</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O2233457</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O2334661</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036566</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O2334661</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O2334661</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3252629</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P4200344</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3252629</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P9995676</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3331222</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3331222</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3331222</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P3455443</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3377543</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O3377543</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P9995676</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O4714645</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036566</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O4714645</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P9995676</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O5511365</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O5511365</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O5511365</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O5511365</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P3455443</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O5511365</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P6677900</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O6565656</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036566</ProdNo>
            <Qty>10</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7847172</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7847172</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P6677900</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7959898</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7959898</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1556678</ProdNo>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7959898</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P3455443</ProdNo>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7959898</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P6677900</ProdNo>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7989497</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1114590</ProdNo>
            <Qty>2</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7989497</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <Qty>2</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O7989497</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>3</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O8979495</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1114590</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O8979495</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1412138</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O8979495</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1445671</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O9919699</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P0036577</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O9919699</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P1114590</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrdNo>O9919699</OrdNo>
            <ProdNo>P4200344</ProdNo>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </OrderLine>
    </ORDERLINES>
</DATA>
```

Comment: I added the code for the XML file. I've already validated it online, so I didn't think that could be the problem.

I'm getting the problem basically as soon as I try to do the import & parse in the JSP.

Edit: As far as I can tell, the import is working, but the parse is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your comments that XML is valid, I suggest you should look into encoding issues.  You can specify the character encoding of input variable like

```
<c:import var="xmlFile" url="CUST.xml" charEncoding="..." />
```

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the tags ... it should be part of `import` tag not the `parse` tag. Now corrected

Comment: Well, that changed the error. :(

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/utils/PrefixResolver

Comment: Well...I loaded another XML file into the JSP and it worked fine, so something is definitely up with this XML file.

Comment: Do you have xalan.jar in your classpath?

Comment: I messed around with the capitalization in the elements of the XML file, and by some miracle got the file to actually parse in the JSP. Problem is, now I'm having a problem with PrefixResolver because of another line:
    <x:forEach select="$myDoc/Data/Customers/Customer">